# Which item is the most cost effective for a Bruiser?

Tags: league-of-legends

When you think of a Bruiser you know that you need tankiness and damage.  I was just wondering which item by itself is the most cost effective to run against the average none double ap team.

Comment: What do you mean average none double AP? As in the top laner is NOT an AP carry?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Right now, Ninja Tabi they are so cheap as an early tier 2 boot for speed and the passive on them is amazing for the money.-

Comment: Well ninja tabi are strong against auto attackers. Bruisers are generally better with tenacity, so merc treads usually win. CC is more of a threat than auto attacks in the majority of games. Agreed tabi's are cheap, but they are very situational.

Comment: I agree with @Theorise here. Tenacity is the better choice for a bruiser.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, on most Bruisers one of my first real items is The Brutalizer. Very cost efficient (Only costs leet, or 1337) and in return you get 25 Attack Damage, decent +15 ArPen along with a bonus of 10% CDR so you can keep on harrassing and dealing more damage since your abilities cooldown faster.

Answer (score 0):

Individually, Aegis of the Legion offers a lot of stats for a little under 2k, especially if you have an ally with it as well. You get 30 armour, 39 MR, 270  health and 8 ad for 1925g, and 42 armour, 54 mr and 16 ad if you have an ally with it as well, counting the auras.

Answer (score 0):

I would also consider Atma's Impaler, it is a great bruiser weapon due to its extra damage being based on your HP.